# Wordpress multisite install on two subdomains, each belonging to a separate domain

Tags: multisite

I would like to do a WordPress Multisite install on two subdomains. I can't use the main domains as they both have other sites running on them. But when these two are done they will need to be redirected.

Setup is:

```
new.site1.com -> will become site1.com when done
new.site2.com -> will become site2.com when done
```

Can I do this with [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/installation/) or otherwise? The DNS looks like it screws up, saying it can't find NS####.new.site1.com. Or should I do a multisite in this case? I thought it'd be better for the client if there was a central admin so he doesn't have to log into two sites, but if it can't be done maybe I'll have to go with two sites.